# Probability at least 3 never respond on a questionnaire

Tags: probability

When sent a questionnaire, $30\%$ of the recipients respond immediately. Of those who do not respond immediately, $45\%$ respond when sent a follow-up letter. A recipient responding to the questionnaire is independent of other recipients.

If the questionnaire is sent to $4$ persons and a follow-up letter is sent to any of the 4 who do not respond immediately, what is the probability that at least $3$ never respond? Options are:

A: $0.04$

B: $0.09$

C: $0.14$

D: $0.16$

E: $0.35$

$P(X\geq3) = P(X=3)+P(X=4)$ Probability that $4$ never respond is easy as it is just $${4\choose0}(.3)^0(.7*.55)^4=(.385)^4$$ Now $P(X=3)$ is split between them responding on $1^{st}$ mail and not one the second, or not responding on first and doing so on the second. This is

$${4\choose1}(.385)^3(.3)+{4\choose1}(.385)^3(.45)$$ The final answer is $$(.385)^4+4(.385)^3(.3)+4(.385)^3(.45)=.19317$$ which is not one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that a particular person does *not* respond is $0.7\cdot 0.55$.  That's the probability for not responding immediately and not responding to the follow up.

The probability that a particular person does respond is $(1-0.7\cdot 0.55)$.   That's simply the probability for *not* not responding.   We're not really interested in *when* they might do so (immediate or follow-up), just *whether* they do so.

So the probability mass function for exactly $x$ non-responders is simply a binomial distribution *pmf*.   Specifically: $$\mathsf P(X=x) ~=~\binom 4x (1-0.7\cdot 0.55)^{4-x}(0.7\cdot 0.55)^x\qquad\big[x\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}\big]$$

Comment: So the answer for choosing 3 non-responders is going to be $${4\choose 3}(.615)(.385)^3?$$